# Ошибка протокола при запросе с Android клиента на PHP сервер

Tags: php, android, клиент-сервер

Пытаюсь создать Android клиент использую Retrofit, сервер на PHP возвращает список пользователей из БД. Не могу получить ответ от сервера, приходит только 
ERROR:: Unexpected status line: J������
Пробовал HttpURLConnection, та же ошибка, из-за чего она может появляться?

Вот небольшая часть сервера

```
if (isset($_GET["action"])) { 
   $action = $_GET['action'];
}
if($action == "select_all_users")   
{
    $pdo = Tools::connect();
    $ps = $pdo->query('select * from Users');
    while($row=$ps->fetch())
    {
        $output[]=$row;
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

А это клиент:

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3306/chatserver/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

            Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
            ChatInterface client = retrofit.create(ChatInterface.class);
            Call<ArrayList<User>> call = client.resp();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<User>> call, Response<ArrayList<User>> response) {
                Log.d("==================", "================== " + response.code());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("============= ERROR: ", String.valueOf(t.getMessage()));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Ошибка, потому что, вы пытаетесь вывести массив через оператор echo.

Comment: Пытался вывести и через print, и просто одну строку через echo, то же самое

Comment: @СтепанДомчак, чтобы понять почему приходит не то, отлаживайте сначала в браузере php-скрипты. И зачем вы пытаетесь печатать простой php-массив? Как вы его в приложении прочитаете? Вам нужно использовать JSON, в Retrofit как раз есть встроенные средства для работы с JSON. Нужно показать, как это сделать? Выложите структуру массива.

Comment: @КириллМалышев
Вот так JSON-массив в браузере отобразился
     [{"_id":"1","name":"TestName","ip_address":"127.0.0.1"},
      {"_id":"2","name":"TestName2","ip_address":"127.0.0.2"}]

если можно покажите как это сделать.
Может проблема в интерфейсе Retrofit?

    public interface ChatInterface {
        @GET("/?action=select_all_users/")
        Call<ArrayList<User>> resp();
    }

Comment: @СтепанДомчак, проверьте кодировку файла на сервере. Если это UTF-8 with BOM, замените на UTF-8. В любом случае замените на UTF-8.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, файл был в UTF-8

Comment: @СтепанДомчак, я сейчас опишу, как правильно отправить ваш запрос и получить ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Что мы имеем.**

Вам необходимо с помощью GET-запроса отправить на сервер один параметр. В ответ вы получите JSON вида

```
[{"_id":"1","name":"TestName","ip_address":"127.0.0.1"}, {"_id":"2","name":"TestName2","ip_address":"127.0.0.2"}]
```

**Шаг 1.**

С помощью сайта http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ (или вручную) создаём из

```
{"_id":"1","name":"TestName","ip_address":"127.0.0.1"}
```

класс User:

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("_id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("ip_address")
@Expose
private String ipAddress;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getIpAddress() {
return ipAddress;
}

public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
}

}
```

**Шаг 2.**

Описываем интерфейс (API):

```
public interface ChatInterface {
    // Так как значение параметра запроса известно, указываем его сразу
    @POST("/api/script.php?action=select_all_users")  // Путь до скрипта от корня сайта
    Call<List<User>> getUsers();
}
```

**Шаг 3**

Делаем запрос и обрабатываем ответ.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.site.ru") //Базовая часть адреса
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Конвертер, необходимый для преобразования JSON'а в объекты
                .build();
ChatInterface api = retrofit.create(ChatInterface.class); //Создаем объект, при помощи которого будем выполнять запросы
Call<List<User>> call = api.getUsers();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            List<User> = response.body();
            Обрабатываем результат
        } else {
            // Произошла ошибка
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
        // Произошла ошибка
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Нашел еще ошибку в конфигурации сервера, эмулятор не видел нужную страницу.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=$ps->fetch())
{
    print_r($row);
}
```